# angular6 - infinite loop running when i call method from a Angular 6 class inside template

Tags: angular6, bind, ngfor, infinity

when i try to bind name using method in *ngFor loop,  infinite loop is running   on my angular 6 project.why is that happening? and please recommend a solution. thank you...

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of MenuList"> 
     <span>{{bindMenuNames(menu.FullNameSpace)}}</span> 
  </div>

 bindMenuNames(FullNameSpace): string 
  {
        console.log(FullNameSpace);
        let menuname: string;
        switch (FullNameSpace)
        {
            case "Message_Centrel":
                menuname = "Messaging";
                break;

            case "Admin":
                menuname = "Admin"
                break;
            case "Catalog":
                menuname = "Course Authoring"
                break;
           default:
                menuname = ""
                break;
        }
       return menuname;
    }
```

[image: please see following image]

Comment: Code looks good to me, Can you check MenuList length?

Comment: yes you can use this line to check length of menulist >>> *ngIf="MenuList ?.length > 0"  <<<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at ts file:

```
public obj = {'Message_Centrel': 'Messaging', 'Admin': 'Admin', 'Catalog': 
             'Course Authoring'}
```

at html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of MenuList"> 
 <span>{{obj[menu.FullNameSpace] ? obj[menu.FullNameSpace] : '-'}}</span> 
</div>
```